# Any suggestions to improve solr regex search performance?

Tags: regex, solr

In Solr I've got the following field for performing exact phrase regex searches on text fields (each > 1KB):

```
<fieldType name="text_keyword_lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

- Regex searches for the beginning of the text are super fast as
  expected (`/sear.* ph.ase.*/`);
- Others, middle and end (`/.*sear.* ph.ase.*/`, `/.*sear.* ph.ase/`) are a
  slow (searching within 200,000 documents in solr takes arround
  900ms on my workstation);

The requirement is to be able to search several hundred million documents within seconds.
Any suggestions on improving the performance of the latter two?
Or maybe a suggestion on different approach/tools?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `.*` in your regex?

Comment: @MikeM Sorry, there was a formatting error in the post. `.*` indicates that there can be zero or more characters.

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering what purpose they serve if you are performing "exact phrase regex searches".

Comment: @MikeM I guess that phrase is not completely clear. By "exact phrase regex searches" I mean that I need to perform phrase searches with regular expressions and search results should return exact matches only. That is why I use KeywordTokenizerFactory to tokenize the text as a single token.

Comment: The `.*` are too liberal and greedy and should be avoided where possible as they will degrade performance (`.*?` is usually better as it _usually_ results in less backtracking). If you edited your question and described exactly the purpose of each regex, someone may be able to better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory). Your index will grow, but the speed will improve.

Comment: It should be a lot faster then wildcard queries. Otherwise you can speed up wilcards at beginning with http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory